# Implicit Differentiation Sympy

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy, implicit, differentiation

I've been doing derivatives in sympy, and I didn't know how that would syntactically be written. I tried looking it up, but none of the solutions made sense. For example, if I'm trying to differentiate `x**5 + y**2 + z**4 = 8xyz` by computation, how would I do that? Would z be a symbol, or a function like in regular derivatives? Thank you.

Comment: Are you doing derivatives or do you try to integrate? You question is not clear about that. Then you should also specify which derivative you want, with respect to which varibale or how you want to integrate the expression, what your integration interval is.

Comment: Oh, sorry for that typo there. I'm trying to differentiate with respect to z.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For two variables you can use `idiff`.

In your case, the simplest way is to set `x` and `y` to be functions of `z`, like

```
x = Function('x')(z)
y = Function('y')(z)
```

Then normal `diff(expr, z)` will take the derivative correctly.

Comment: So after reading some documentation I got it to work using idiff, but not quite sure what you're saying about using regular diff and setting x and y as functions. I keep getting weird results. Shouldn't z be a function of x or y, depending on which one you're taking with respect to?

Comment: Sure. You said in the question that you are taking the derivative with respect to `z`.

Answer (score 1):

You commented you used [idiff](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/geometry/utils.html?highlight=idiff#sympy.geometry.util.idiff), here is the corresponding code for those who want to know:

```
from sympy import symbols, idiff, simplify

x, y, z = symbols('x y z')
ex = x**5 + y**2 + z**4 - 8*x*y*z
ex_d = simplify(idiff(ex,(x,y),z))
display(ex_d)
```

[image]

In `idiff(ex,(x,y),z)`, `(x,y)` are the dependent variables, and `z` the variable the derivative is being taken with respect to.